# How to generate random numbers between 0.3 and 0.35 in php

Tags: php, random, numbers

I tried to use the following

```
rand()/getrandmax()*0.35+0.3
```

but still it generates the number greater than max limit. lower limit is not violated but max one is.

Comment: What kind of numbers are you seeing?

Answer (score 6):

To correct your own code, you need to add the lower boundary and multiply the random value (`rand()/getrandmax()`) by the difference of the upper and lower bounds (0.35 - 0.3).

```
rand()/getrandmax()*0.05+0.3
```

Comment: +1, although any method is still subject to the inherent accuracy problems in double precision floating point numbers, so you may still get numbers that are very very slightly out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats the logic I want to know.Thanks again

Comment: @user1369905 You're welcome; just know that m7o's code is probably more accurate. Your code, even what I adapted, works with double precision and can loose accuracy pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

```
   $min = 30;
   $max = 35;
   $accuracy = 1000000;

   $random_number = rand($min*$accuracy, $max*$accuracy)/(100*$accuracy);
```

As the PHP manual says:

```
   rand(int $min, int $max)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

And if you use PHP < 4.2.0 call at least srand(); each time before you create the random number.

Answer (score 0):

your interval is 0.05, so you should divide by 20 (or multiply by 0.05) instead of multiplying by 0.35

Answer (score -1):

```
$min = .3;
$max = .35;

echo rand($min, $max);
```

That's the easiest way I know.

Comment: -1 because this is undefined behavior. [The manual](http://php.net/rand) clearly states that the arguments, if provided, must be integers.

Answer (score -1):

The prototype for this function is:

```
int rand ( int $min , int $max )
```

so just call:

```
rand (0.3, 0.35 );
```

Comment: 0.3 and 0.35 aren't exactly int.

Comment: Thats true, i should have read over my answer first. Just multiply by 100 as above.